# Continuous Integration without the "Build"

Tags: html, unix, continuous-integration

Our group uses Visual Sourcesafe as a file repository for all of our "content" (HTML, CSS, Javascript, JSP).  None of it requires building or compilation but we would like to automate the copying of it to a Unix dev server upon check-in.

I have used Cruisecontrol.NET in the past for CI at other companies but it was for .NET.  What would be the easiest way to achieve our current requirements?  Would using CruiseControl.NET be overkill or even a good idea?  Thanks in advance.

-Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like overkill for a CI tool.

Visual SourceSafe and other version control systems should have hooks allowing you to automate a simple file copy operation.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302175.aspx

> Use events, such as OnBeforeCheckout
>   or OnAfterCheckIn to automate your
>   process.

Whether this makes sense for you depends on a couple of factors.  If you are talking about a large, geographically team with only change based deployment then yes, those are valid concerns.  If you only have a few local developers and you deploy the world on each copy operation, then no, I don't think you'd need a CI tool.

This is not to say other reasons may influence you to use a CI tool, testing for instance.  Your problem might also be solved by running a polling script on the Unix box to sync the source control with the dev server.  I guess the main point is, if you are deploying all non-compiled software, why do you have a separate source control and dev server?  You're deployment can be done by a source control tool.  If it is only for backup, there are plenty of existing solutions for that problem.

Comment: Thanks for responding!  I know that it is overkill but would rather configure than develop a COM based wrapper to automate this process.

Comment: If you change your mind here is a link describing some of the process for one way to use OnAfterCheckin.  http://vbcity.com/forums/t/54079.aspx

Comment: Also, there are plenty of alternative free quality source control systems which should allow you to configure a solution, rather than develop one.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  I looked into this but would this be a good idea to support multiple developers checking in code?  Since the code runs as a plug-in, it first has to be deployed locally to all the clients.  Secondly, you cannot centrally control the file copy because developers are checking in files at different times.  So you could run into competition issues.  Thoughts?

Comment: Updated answer with thoughts on when OnAfterCheckin.

Answer (score 1):

Sean,

Our AnthillPro customers do this kind of thing pretty frequently (and we even do it internally when new content is committed for our website). It's a really good idea, totally appropriate for a CI tool, and you can get quality feedback if you wire in some automated functional / regression tests.

- Eric

Comment: Thanks Eric.  I will definitely take a look.  Does Anthill Pro support differential gets (changed content from last check-in) from SourceSafe?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Hudson http://hudson-ci.org/

It is easy to configure, is completely GUI (unless you want to go into the details), and has a plugin for Visual Sourcecafe http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Visual+SourceSafe+Plugin

While CI would probably be overkill for what you are trying to do, since Hudson is all GUI and easy to use, you would not spend a lot of time just trying to configure it.

Hudson also has plugins for copying stuff over to other systems, and so it would be easy to deploy your content to another system.

Comment: Eric, thanks for responding.  I was able to do a proof of concept using Visual SOurcesafe and Cruisecontrol.NET.  Do you know if Visual Sourcesafe supports differential gets?  I only want to pull the changed content since the last check-in and not everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about the process, get in touch with a hosted CI provider, such as MikeCI, a quick message on their support board will get you the answer. I don't see why triggering a "build" can't be replaced with copy and paste!